# Stacklayout not fill whole screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin, stacklayout

There is a little dark space on the screen. I dont want these dark space here. How can i delete or make bigger my stacklayout ?

My xaml :

```
 <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" >...  </StackLayout>
```

[image]

This is my HomePage's xaml file :

https://www.paste.tc/homepagexaml

Comment: What is the StackLayout inside of? Perhaps its container isn't asking for the full screen height, and also needs `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand". OR put StackLayout inside `<Grid>`, which by default will fill the screen. Then you could set Grid's BackgroundColor to fill that black area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:
I changed Targeted Api version a lower one. I think my screen resolution was too high and that lower api version does not support that huge resolution. And i saw that blank spot on phone screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the value of property `HorizontalOptions` of `StackLayout` to `FillAndExpand`,just as follows:

```
 <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow"> 

    <Button  Text="test"  HeightRequest="80"  />

</StackLayout>
```

Of course, you can also use `Grid` to achieve this. You can set the special height for the control you need, and set the height of other `RowDefinition`  to `*`, it will occupy the other space of the screen.

You can refer to the following code:

```
   <Grid  BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Color="Green" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: This doesn't effect. This dark space shown whole application screens. Splashscreen and other tabbed screens.

Comment: Could you please post the whole code of  `thispage.xaml`?

Comment: Zhang I edit question. Also there is my homepage.xaml : https://www.paste.tc/homepagexaml

Comment: I found that you haven't set the value of property `VerticalOptions`  and property `HorizontalOptions`  of the outer  `StackLayout`  to `FillAndExpand`.

Comment: My all page's has this dark space. I think my app work in this little screen. Is there any setting about this ? Maybe app shell has a property and i changed it accidently.

Comment: Zhang I changed targeted api version and problem solved.

Comment: Congrats and happy coding. :)